# Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: GD is either not installed or not enabled, check your configuration

Tags: kohana-3

i am getting the following exception in kohana 3
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: GD is either not installed or not enabled, check your configuration
please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install GD for your PHP installation. I'm going to assume you're using the PHP packages from the Ubuntu, etc ... repositories in which case you need to install php5-gd.

```
sudo aptitude install php5-gd
```

Then restart Apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If not then you need to consult the documentation for the software you use.